# SQL logic needed help possible subquerying

Tags: sql

Question from an exercise that I am not able to solve. I do not have enough knowledge.

query = For all cases where the same reviewer rated the same movie twice and gave it a higher rating the second time, return the reviewer's name and the title of the movie

If I try this:

```
SELECT  title, max (stars)
FROM Movie
  JOIN Rating on Movie.mID = Rating.mID
```

I get only one movie, I want to be able to see all movies from table "Movie" and the highest rate in case they have more than one rate in table "Rating"

Comment: Help us help you - share the table structures, some sample data and the result you'd like to get for it

Comment: Also, please [edit] your post and tag it with the [tag:rdbms] you are using

Comment: Please provide us more context, the community here might quickly downvote this post the moment they see the word "assignment" and no code in the post. 

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Alsways read your textbook/introduction & the manual for functionality you are using. Here, re how group by & aggregate functions like MAX work together. When clear this will be a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask], [Help] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title.

Answer (score 0):

What I get from question I guess this query will solve your problem

```
SELECT
  mov.`title`,
  MAX(rat.`rating`)
FROM
  rating rat
  JOIN movie mov
    ON rat.`movie_id` = mov.`id`
WHERE mov.`id` IN
  (SELECT
    r.`movie_id`
  FROM
    rating r
  GROUP BY r.`movie_id`
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
GROUP BY mov.`id`
```

Movie Table

[image]

Rating Table

[image]

Result

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Use LEFT OUTER JOIN, to bring all values of the 'Movie' table.
> Add Group by Clause to get the Title record only one, ie The Max Stars
> in case the stars value is null, handle the output.
> MaxRating alias for the max value

The script eg.

SELECT Movie.title, max(IFNULL(Rating.stars,0)) MaxRating
FROM Movie
LEFT JOIN Rating
on Movie.mID = Rating.mID
group by Movie.title

Comment: In question, he asked to get movie title only when the rating is giving twice or more than one. what I get from his question.